# Discord-js ошибка в таймере

Tags: javascript, таймер, discord-api

Код ниже отлавливает время до voiceStateUpdate и во время. Цель узнать разницу и выдать монету за минутное нахождение на сервере.

```
function updateClock(timeback) {
    var now = new Date();
    console.log("U:"+now.getMinutes());
    console.log("N:" + timeback);
    if (now.getMinutes() != timeback) {
        console.log("POINTS!")
        userData.points++;
        });
    }
}
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', function (oldMember, newMember) {
    var now2 = new Date();
    setInterval(updateClock(now2.getMinutes()), 3000)}

});
```

Выдает ошибку :

```
timers.js:435
    throw new TypeError('"callback" argument must be a function');
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно устанавливаете функцию в `setInterval`, вам нужно передать функцию, а вы передаёте результат функции `updateClock`

так скорее всего сработает:

```
setInterval(()=>{updateClock(now2.getMinutes())}, 3000)
```